# How to create_reference_table from another DB (not postgres)?

Tags: citus

I trying to create new db, when tables in it, then make them distributed, but can't use create_reference_table() in new db (it's not found).
If I try to run create_reference_table('newbie.schema.new_table) I will get error "ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented":

```
CREATE DATABASE newbie;
SELECT * from master_add_node('citus-worker1', 5432);
SELECT * from master_add_node('citus-worker2', 5432);
SELECT run_command_on_workers('CREATE DATABASE newbie;');

\c newbie

create table new_table
SELECT create_reference_table('schema.new_table');
```

leads to
ERROR:  function create_reference_table(unknown) does not exist
looks like vicious circle (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `CREATE EXTENSION Citus` on all databases separately (If you want to distribute some tables in those databases of course). Citus stores the distributed object metadata inside the relevant database.

These steps should work:

```sql
\c newbie
CREATE EXTENSION Citus;
CREATE SCHEMA s;
CREATE TABLE s.new_table(id int);
SELECT create_reference_table('s.new_table');
```

If you run a `CREATE DATABASE ...` when Citus extension is enabled, you can see the help messages:

```
postgres=# create database new_db;
NOTICE:  Citus partially supports CREATE DATABASE for distributed databases
DETAIL:  Citus does not propagate CREATE DATABASE command to workers
HINT:  You can manually create a database and its extensions on workers.
```

Also do not forget to run `master_add_node()` to add the worker nodes in the new database as well. The worker metadata is stored in the associated database as well.

Comment: Thanks! It works. It's was a bit tricky with docker: I had to create separate Dockerfile's for master and workers to run CREATE DATABASE ... and CREATE EXTENSION Citus; on workers and the same plus creation of tables on master. But it become to work unbelievable slowly -- request to three distributed tables with joins needs 5-7 seconds

Comment: You should run these `CREATE EXTENSION Citus` and `master_add_node()` calls only once per database, and after that things should be as fast as that in a setup with single database in each node. There is a lot of discussion on pros and cons of having multiple databases in a single PostgreSQL server, and I personally prefer having multiple schemas in a single database in a machine. You can find one such discussion [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/016439c9-8017-e319-bd2f-893b1a8cd091%40hogranch.com#9987436602d187df7a04b1c983e5e983)

Comment: ok, thanks, unfortunately I'm not allowed to make decisions about db architecture on this project. Slow query exec was caused because I did request to not colocated table ( .